# Metadata Extractor Unable to read Camera specific Orientation

Tags: java, image, image-rotation, metadata-extractor

I have an image which contains 2 Orientation attributes. When I try to read the meta data of the image, it gives out the value from the second orientation attribute always.

Is there a way to read the first orientation value?

I have attached 2 files. 1 is the image and 2 is the meta data of the image in the form of text file.

1. Image
   [image]
2. MetaData file[image]

I am using the code as shown below:

```
public int getImage(String name,String outputFileName) throws ImageProcessingException, IOException {

        Metadata metadata;
        try {
            File f = new File(name);
            metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(f);

            for (Directory directory : metadata.getDirectories()) {
                for (Tag tag : directory.getTags()) {

                    if(tag.getTagName().equals("Orientation")){
                        final Integer index = directory.getInteger(274);
                        System.out.format("[%s] - %s = %s",
                                directory.getName(), tag.getTagName(),index);
                        BufferedImage image = getRotatedImage(f,index);
                        File img = new File(outputFileName+".png");
                        ImageIO.write(image,"png",img);
                        //return 0;

                    }
                }
                if (directory.hasErrors()) {
                    for (String error : directory.getErrors()) {
                        System.err.format("ERROR: %s", error);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (ImageProcessingException e) {
            System.out.println("Image processing exception while rotating image");
            throw e;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO exception while rotating image");
            throw e;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Stack Overflow has removed the metadata from your JPEG (or it was never there.)

Comment: There was meta data in the image but seems like stack overflow uses a BufferedImageReader which removes the metadata :D

Answer (score 0):

There are two orientations because one is for the image, and the other is for the thumbnail.

Rather than iterating over all directories, get just the directory you want via `Metadata.getFirstDirectoryOfType` or `Metadata.getDirectoriesOfType`. You can then ask that directory directly for the tag's value. Again, there is no need to iterate all tags -- that just wastes resources (CPU/memory).

Comment: actually there is no way to fetch the image orientation using MetaData extractor... I managed to resolve the issue by reading image using BufferredImageReader and then applying transformation as per thumbnail orientation. Although it is tough to explain what the problem was exactly, thanks for your help anyways

Comment: If the orientation is there, metadata-extractor will find it. If you believe there's a bug in the library, please open an issue and attach an image: https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/issues/new